# SFTP transfer file and move file to folder

Tags: vbscript, sftp

This is my first post so please excuse my ignorance. I am using a vbscript to zip all .csv type files in a particular folder. After some google searches, I have found a workable [vbscript](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Q_24083472.html) to do this and have enabled a scheduled task to automate this.

What I need to do next is to transfer the zip file via sftp and then "move" that zip file into another folder. I believe the former can be achieved using pscp.exe via command line but can someone show me how to do the latter?

Basically the zipping will be done twice a day and so it will have a timestamp similar to `yyyymmdd0900.zip` (for 9am schedule) and `yyyymmdd1800.zip` (for 6pm schedule). After the transfer, I want to move (not copy) the zip file generated into another folder.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: Here is some code I slapped together based on some Google searches. It does what I want it to do. Please excuse the "pasting" as i couldn't figure out how to format it properly. Currently, it runs the bat file after copying but I just noticed that i need to send (using PuTTY Secure Copy) the "latest" zip file before moving it to the "completed" folder. Can someone please show me how to do this?

> Zipping the file and rename the zip file

My Code :

```
On Error Resume Next
strFilepath = "c:\files"
strDestination = "c:\files\completed\"
strExtension = "csv"

strYear = Year(Now)

strMonth = Right("0" & Month(Now), 2)

strDay = Right("0" & Day(Now), 2)

strHour = Right ("0" & Hour(Now), 2)

strMinute = Right ("0" & Minute (Now), 2)


strZip = strFilepath & "\" & strYear & strMonth & strDay & strHour & strMinute & ".zip"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFilepath)

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files

    strFileExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path)
        If LCase(strFileExt) = LCase(strExtension) Then
        ZipFile objFile.Path, strZip
    End If
Next

Sub ZipFile(strFileToZip, strArchive)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(strArchive) Then
        Set objTxt = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strArchive)
        objTxt.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))
        objTxt.Close
    End If

    Set objApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    intCount = objApp.NameSpace(strArchive).Items.Count + 1

    objApp.NameSpace(strArchive).CopyHere strFileToZip

    Do
        WScript.Sleep 200
        set objNameSpace = objApp.NameSpace(strArchive)

        If Not objNameSpace is nothing Then        
            If objNameSpace.Items.Count = intCount Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

>Move file to a different folder and then run a bat file to secury copy file to a FTP location

'Vars

Dim objFSO, objFileCopy, objFileDelete, dot, files, file

Dim strDestination, folder, subfolder, fileCount, strFilePath

'Strings

strDestination = "C:\Files\Completed\"

strFilePath = "C:\Files"

    set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject") 

    set folder = objFSO.getFolder(strFilePath) 

For Each file In folder.files

Set objFileCopy = objFSO.GetFile(file)

       If objFSO.GetExtensionName(file) = "zip" Then                
        objFSO.MoveFile objFileCopy.Path, strDestination
       End If


Next

Dim shell

Set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")

Shell.run "C:\testsend.bat"

Set shell=nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

sftp client provides a means to change working directory on the host before performing any file transfers.  It would be better to thus transfer the file directly to the target location.

NOTE:  The above answer was a result of misunderstanding the question.  I read it to mean the file had to be moved on the destination but the real operation was to move the file on the origin.

I found the following example code that moves a file after checking that it exists.  Wildcards are allowed for the source parameter but then FileExists may not work.  Requires vbscript 2.0 to work.

```
<%
dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.html") Then
   filesys.MoveFile "c:\sourcefolder\anyfile.html", "c:\destfolder\"
End If
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I should have made it clear that the transfer is a remote location and the "move" I was talking about it local to the box the file resides on. I also want this automated after I perform the zip and then get sftp to transfer it from whatever location the file resides. Hope i'm making some sense.

Comment: SFTP doesn't have a concept of working directory at all - according to the standard all paths must be absolute. It's the client software, that emulates current directory concept.

Comment: @Eugene, good clarification.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will move a file to the specified location.

```
Sub Move_File(Source_File, Destination_Folder)
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.MoveFile Source_File, Destination_Folder
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we use the above logic to transfer the file to a remote directory in a Unix system?...and if it needs Username and Password to login to the Unix system, can i pass the them too in this?..thanks.